# Maror- common lettuce

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, marror-bitter-herbs

Rav Dovid Feinstein in Kol Dodi perek 15:18 writes that the common custom is to use romaine lettuce for maror.However, he mentions that he heard that a renowned Gaon of recent times who permitted common lettuce for maror.

Does anyone know who this Gaon was or if there is a posek who allows common lettuce fir marror?

Comment: I seem to recal hearing that R' Chaim Kanievsky uses the stump from common lettuce.

Comment: See [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/310), where [Shalom](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) says that R' Yaakov Kaminetsky ate iceberg lettuce for maror. Also [this article](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/Bugs_in_Lettuce/) and [this article](http://www.vosizneias.com/161668/2014/04/13/new-york-frescada-the-new-maror/) mention the claim that R' Aharon Kotler ate iceberg lettuce for maror.

Comment: Romaine lettuce and iceberg lettuce are the same species. (That's not a proof but it may support that there is no halachic difference between them.)

Comment: Well Rav Dovid explains that he spoke to a botanist who said they are all one family (not exact words ,just writing the main idea I rem)

Comment: What is "common lettuce"?

Comment: @msh210 Many years ago, a grand-daughter excitedly informed me after going shopping with her parents for the first time, "Lettuce comes in balls!!" (and not just in bags)

Comment: @msh210 - I think he means iceberg lettuce. To me it doesn't taste bitter at all. As a matter of fact, it has NO taste! It's a taste ... err ... I mean, waste of time.

Comment: @sabbahillel - Yes it does. Did you tell your granddaughter that cabbages have heads?

Comment: @msh210 The reason for lettuce being maror is that is starts out sweet (like the beginning of the galus mitzrayim) and becomes bitter if allowed to stay in the ground.

Comment: https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_using_horseradish_for_maror/ footnote 16